# How to do mvn scm plugin anonymous pserver cvs access

Tags: java, maven, cvs

I'd like to use the maven scm plugin to export my code from CVS with an anonymous user. I'm not using the CVS client for ease of use reasons (download mvn and eclipse, and you're good to go to join my project, on any platform).

However, I can't seem to get the mvn scm plugin to checkout code with anonymous pserver access. It complains that CVS requires a password. Am I missing something? this is the command I'm executing:

```
mvn scm:export 
    -DconnectionUrl=scm:cvs:pserver:anonymous@speedforge.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/speedforge:speedforge 
    -DexportDirectory=export 
    -DscmVersion=v004 
    -DscmVersionType=tag
```

(You can run that directly, it's an open source project on source forge)

I'm getting the following error from the scm plugin:

```
org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException: Wrong Password.
```

I'm using mvn 2.2.1 on a mac:

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_26
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.7.2" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

Although the mvn scm documentation seems to mention anonymous cvs access, it doesn't really come with examples on how to do just that: http://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html

Can anybody help me getting anonymous pserver access working with the mvn scm plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try providing an empty password in the URL:

```
mvn scm:export 
  -DconnectionUrl=scm:cvs:pserver:anonymous:@speedforge.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/speedforge:speedforge 
  -DexportDirectory=export 
  -DscmVersion=v004 
  -DscmVersionType=tag
```

(notice the extra `:` between the username and the `@`-sign separating the credentials from the host name.)

Comment: tried that already. Same result as with -Dpassword= and -Dpassword=anonymous

Answer (score 0):

The same command works for me on my linux box with maven 3. The output follows for reference. You may want to also check the version of the plugin getting used.

```
$ mvn scm:export -DconnectionUrl=scm:cvs:pserver:anonymous@speedforge.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/speedforge:speedforge -DexportDirectory=speedforge -DexportDirectory=export -DscmVersion=v004 -DscmVersionType=tag
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.5:export (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/user/work-folder/export && cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:anonymous@speedforge.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/speedforge -q export -rv004 speedforge
[INFO] Working directory: /home/user/work-folder/export
[ERROR] Didn't find password for CVSROOT ':pserver:anonymous@speedforge.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/speedforge'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.275s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 31 07:53:40 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 23:01:09+0530)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_25/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-12-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Funny that it does report an [ERROR] but continues. I'll check my plugin versions and let you know if it worked. Thanks for helping, much appreciated.